stream_gpu-inl.h:159: Check failed: err == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0) : Create cusolver handle failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dmlc::Error'
what():  [11:16:58] ../include/mshadow/./stream_gpu-inl.h:159: Check failed: err == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0) : Create cusolver handle failed
thinking that it is version confliction. but i tried many version but still cannot find any version that could solve this problem.
the version that i use in my project
mxnet: mxnet-cu110
cudnn: 8.9.1.23-1+cuda11.8
cuda: 11.8.0-1
nvidia-driver: 560.28.03
the verion of cuda try 11.0, 11.8,both not solving the problem.
mxnet seems not support cudnn9.x so cudnn8 is install but not work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
